# I can't hear voice after successful calling a number with AT command

Tags: at-command, modem

I have successfully placed a call with ATDTn but i cant hear anything from the recipient.  I have googled but no help. It is a voice modem. Is there anything i am doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
if ((m_serialPort != null) && (m_serialPort.IsOpen))
            {
                SerialPort port = m_serialPort;

                string t = port.ReadExisting();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT+FCLASS=8" + "\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT+CVHU" + ";\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT+CRC=1" + ";\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT+CLIP=1" + ";\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("ATM3" + "\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                string cmd = "ATDT";
                string phoneNumber = tocall;
                port.WriteLine(cmd + phoneNumber + ";\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT^DDSETEX=2" + "\r");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
                port.WriteLine("AT+VTX");


                txtCallStatus.Text = "Calling";
                Speak(1, "You are calling " + txtDial.Text);

                callchecker.Start();
                bCall.Content = "End Call";
                cbComPort.IsEnabled = false;                    
            }
```

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Comment: @gunr2171 I yanked the C# tag on this. It's really language-independent in the sense that the AT command set is what the OP is having trouble with. Not sure there's any code for the OP to give us other than `ATDTn`, so your comment may not apply. As far as question quality, it's certainly missing a dump of attempts that the OP has made to solve it.

Comment: Sorry for not providing a code earlier. i have edited my question with my code. I can make a call but cannot hear the other party

Answer (score 1):

For a full listing of AT commands, [see this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set).
For a full listing of Voice Modem commands, [see this wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voice_modem_command_set).

In general, you want to do this:

1) Request voice modem mode:

```
AT+FCLASS=8  (on some older modems, use AT#CLS=8 )
```

2) Speaker on until remote carrier detected / busy detection, and dial.

```
ATm1x3DTxxxxxxx  (Where xxxxxxx is phone number.)
```

Note: in my experience, I always had to run these as two separate commands

Depending on your modem, you may also need to increase the volume with:

```
ATL1, ATL2, or ATL3 (depending on how loud you need it.)
```

To send DTMF tones during the voice call:

```
AT+VTS={x,25}   (where x = digit to dial)
```

Comment: any idea about  how to send audio to GSM modem from my local pc ? so that i can play it while calling ?